# C# ajuda erro com sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

Onde esta o erro ? não faz update de jeito nenhum

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(conexao);
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
      conn.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE PESSOAS SET NOME,ADDRESS = @NOME,@ADDRESS  WHERE ID = @CODIGO", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CODIGO",IDregistro);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("NOME", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ADDRESS", textBox2.Text);
try
{
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      MessageBox.Show("Registro Atualizado Com sucesso");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sua `SQL` está **errada**, ***exemplo***:

```
UPDATE PESSOAS SET NOME = @NOME, ADDRESS = @ADDRESS WHERE ID = @CODIGO
```

***Referencia*** [SQL UPDATE Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Comment: Obrigado deu certo apanhei pra xuxu nisso ai !

Comment: Se for a resposta da sua pergunta @carloscoelho aceite como resposta!

Comment: estou esperando os 6 minutos Aqui diz assim você so pode aceitar uma resposta em 6 minutos ,estou esperando